# How to parallelize "for" loops?

Tags: python, parallel-processing

How would one parallelize the following scenario?

```
output = []
time = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  
var_a = 5
var_b = 7

for t in time:
   new_var_a = var_a*t
   new_var_b = some_func(var_a, t)
   add_dict = {"a": new_var_a, "b": new_var_b}
   output.append(add_dict)
```

Is it possible to parallelize this without making a function that takes `var_a` and `var_b` as arguments?

Comment: Order won't matter in this case

Comment: Use multithreading.